# Set mongoose field as type of either String or Number

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a field `example` in my database, which I want it to be either `Number` or `String`:

```
export const mySch = new mongoose.Schema({
    example: {
        type: String,
    },
});
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a type in mongoose `Schema.Types.Mixed` which can be used to save values of any type in the given field. However, I haven't yet found a way to restrict it to just a particular subset of types e.g String and Number.

Here is the link if you want to study in detail yourself: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mongoose Discriminator.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html